# Export eps figures from TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

Section 32 *Externalization Library* of the *pgfmanual* (v2.10) explains how to generate PDF figures and EPS figures. I successfully tried it with PDF output (there is an example with a full explanation in the manual), but failed with EPS (no example provided). Can anyone give me a minimal example?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The manual says that one way is to run `pdftops -eps <pdf file> <eps file>` after a compilation that produces a `.pdf`.

Alternatively, you can use the `external/system call=...` key as described on page 345 of the v2.10 manual. Unfortunately, the way to do it differs slightly between operating systems and TeX distributions. Here are descriptions for the three most common combinations:

---

Under unixy operating systems (**Linux, Mac OS X**) with **TeX Live** (or derivatives like MacTeX), the following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% set up externalization
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi;
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[some graphic]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then you run the file with `latex --shell-escape` (not `pdflatex`!).

---

If you run **TeX Live** under **Windows**, the `;` in the `system call` definition has to be changed to `&&` (that change should also work for at least some shells in other OSes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% set up externalization
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" &&
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi &&
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[some graphic]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and you should compile it with `latex --shell-escape` (I haven't tested this myself, but I'm pretty sure that this will work).

---

If you use **MikTeX** on **Windows**, you need to further change `--shell-escape` to `-enable-write18` and tell TikZ about the change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% set up externalization
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && 
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi &&
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % MikTeX uses a -enable-write18 instead of --shell-escape.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and run with `latex -enable-write18` (not `pdflatex`!).

---

If you want to run `pdflatex` and create an .eps file from the image, replace the `system call` by

```
pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error 
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && % or ;
pdftops -eps "\image".pdf
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out this, but it did not work. I use MikTeX 2.9 with updated packages.

Comment: @MaMing The above works on TeX Live, but I don't have a MikTeX install to test things. Maybe someone else can say why it doesn't work with MikTeX.

Comment: @MaMing: The problem was in the Windows shell. Apparently chaining commands with `;` does not work under Windows. See the updated answer for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!!! It works for my MikTeX, you helped me too much, thanks again.

Comment: Hi when I try your example I'm getting `tikz: Sorry, the system call 'latex -halt-on-error -interaction` error.

What seems to be the problem? I'm using MikTex 2.9 and texmakerx on Win 7

Comment: @dingo: I can't really help you with MikTeX, but I suspect that this isn't the full error message. It's probably best to ask a new question, providing a minimal example, the compilation method and the full error message.

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `;` anyway, because with `;` commands will continue to execute even if the previous one failed.

Comment: How do I remove the suffix from the files? For instance: histogram-figure0.eps ---> histogram.eps

Comment: @JohnTortugo: The suffix is automatically appended in case there are several figures in the file.

Comment: i am using Miktex on Windows and did the same as your post, but i only got `.ps` file, i don't see any `.eps` file

Comment: @scmg: You may want to check if ps2eps is installed. Sorry, but I don't use Miktex so I don't know how to check that.

Comment: @Hoang-NganNguyen thanks, i solved the problem already, although i'm not sure if installing `ps2eps` makes it done or not, since i used `GSview` to convert `.ps` to `.eps`