# Externalize eps figure with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, eps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz)

How make externalize EPS figure with TikZ?

Comment: Regis, does this answer your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8641/86 ? If so, we'll close this as a duplicate.  If not, please edit your question to explain what it is that doesn't work from that question to help people focus their attention on the key issue for you.

Comment: Voting to close as really exact duplicate.

Comment: @Andrew, i see the other question. But i could not do using texlive 2010 on windows.

Comment: @Regis: Then you need to focus your question a little more to explain what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @Andrew, I digit latex myfile.tex --shell-escape but it gave error. Remember, i use TeX Live 2010, PGF/TikZ 2.10 and Windows XP.

Comment: I made the code in the linked question more explicit. If it does not work please add an example and the error message to your question.

Comment: @Regis, please edit your question above with the new details and provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).