# Externalize graphics when using pgfplots doesn't work (MiKTeX 2.9)

Tags: pgfplots, miktex

I'm having problems exporting my pgfplots figures to separate files using the externalize command. I get an error, the central point of which seems to be "Please verify that you have enabled system calls.". I have followed the instructions in the pgfplots manual to do this, however.
I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and Windows 7.

(In a related thread, the poster has the same problem as me: [Attempt to export EPS figures from TikZ fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14030/attempt-to-export-eps-figures-from-tikz-fails) . However, in that case the poster is able to successfully export an image using the command "pdflatex -enable-write18 -output-format=dvi", I don't get that far. I have read that thread carefully but still can't figure out how to solve my problem).

My example is the following, taken from the pgfplots manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] %needed for the MiKTeX compiler

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Our first external graphics example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I compile using the command:

```
pdflatex.exe -shell-escape
```

This gives the following error:

```
entering extended mode
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -enable-write18 -halt
-on-/b/c9/cerror /b/c0/c-interaction=batchmode -jobname "externalizetest-figure0" "\def\tikze
xternalrealjob{externalizetest}\input{externalizetest}"' ========
! Package tikz /b/c9/cError:/b/c0/c Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -enable-write18 -halt-on
-/b/c9/cerror /b/c0/c-interaction=batchmode -jobname "externalizetest-figure0" "\def\tikzexte
rnalrealjob{externalizetest}\input{externalizetest}"' did NOT result in a usabl
e output file 'externalizetest-figure0' (expected one of .epsi:.eps:.ps:). Plea
se verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -
shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or
 maybe the command simply failed? /b/c9/cError /b/c0/cmessages can be found in 'externalizete
st-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

As I understand it, the line

```
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
```

is supposed to replace the command -shell-escape to -enable-write18, which is needed for MiKTeX. Just to make sure that isn't the problem, I tried using the command

```
pdflatex.exe -enable-write18
```

instead, and

```
\tikzexternalize
```

in the .tex file. But that doesn't work either.

I'd be very thankful for help on how to enable system calls with MiKTeX 2.9, or, if the problem lies somewhere else, for thoughts on what might be wrong.

/Andreas

Comment: You can always do it the other way around: Place you plot/diagram in an external file with a full preamble and use the `standalone` class to be able to compile it by itself. You can then use the `standalone` package to strip the preamble when you `\input` it, or include the resulting image directly. The next version of `standalone` will allow you to switch between both and even create the PDF automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I understand you are the author of standalone. Is the package also able to export eps images?

Comment: If you compile the standalone files with normal `latex` then yes.

Comment: I see two possible reasons for the failure: the first is that the system did not allow the system call and the second is that the system call has been started, but failed. In general, if there exists a log file `externalizetest-figure0.log`, the system call has tried to start. If not, you can be sure that the system call did not even start. In that case, the main log file `externalizetest.log` might indicate a small hint of what went wrong. Perhaps it did not find the "pdflatex" command?

Comment: @Martin: I'm using pdflatex. The reason I ask is because I can't find info on how to export eps images in the manual, do you know where I can find such instructions?

Comment: Why do you want to export EPS when you use `pdflatex`? Both `standalone` nor `export` actually export anything, but use either `latex` or `pdflatex` (either automatic or manual) to create a DVI (which can be converted EPS) or PDF file. As said, place the `tikzpicture` in a own file, add a `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{tikz,otherpackages}<libs..>` preamble and compile it with `latex`. Then use `dvips -E` (IIRC) on the DVI file to get a EPS.

Comment: @Christian: After reinstalling and updating MiKTeX (avoiding the update of hyph-utf8, which seems to be having some problems since the new version came out on June 23, so everyone reading this is hereby warned), it now works! I get a separate pdf file containing the image. What I actually need is an eps file, but that's unrelated to the current question. The problem seemed to be related to something else than the system call failing to start, since there was always a file named "externalizetest-figure0.log". I'll never know what, but the update solved the problem.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the answer. The reason I need an eps file is that the journal I'm submitting my article to wants all figures as separate eps files, of all formats.

Comment: See also [How to convert PDF to EPS?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reinstalling and updating MiKTeX 2.9 (avoiding the update of hyph-utf8, which seems to be having some problems since the new version came out on June 23) solved the problem. The above code (using either of the command lines mentioned) now correctly exports the figure to a separate pdf file.

Answer (score 4):

I used to have the same problem. In my environment (Eclipse with Texlipse), the problem was that I specified a temporary output directory. By disabling this, the externalization works. Moreover, I had problem getting my bibliography updated. This was solved, too.
The disadvantage is only that the directory looks messy.
Cheers,
Roman

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error 11+ years later and I'm posting this solution I eventually figured out for anyone else that runs into it.

- MiKTeX 4.9
- Windows 10, 22H2

1. After installation, open TeXworks. Go to the "Edit" menu and select
   the "Preferences" listing
2. When the "TeXworks Preferences" window opens, go to the "Typsetting" tab
3. On the "Typesetting" tab, go to the "Processing tools" section
4. In the "Processing tools" section select the text compiler you are using (example: "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX") and then click the "Edit..." button
5. In the "Tool Configuration" window that opens, go to the "Arguments" section and click the "+" button
6. In the new listing that appears (usually `NewArgument`) delete the current text and paste `--tex-option=--shell-escape` in its place
7. Use the 'up' and 'down' arrows to move this new listing above the `$fullname` listing
8. Click the "OK" button on the "Tool Configuration" window, then click the "OK" button on the "TeXworks Preferences" window

External graphs using pgfplots should now work.