# Externalize TikZ with TeXstudio and MikTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I have the same problem as written here before, but the externalization doesn't work. I always get the following message:

```
tikz: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interact
```

I try to input some simulation result from Matlab via `matlab2tikz`. If I run my `.tex` file without externalization it works just fine, but if I write

```
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzfig/]
```

it does not work any more.

Here is a part of my header:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzfig/]
```

I also saw the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22374/externalize-graphics-when-using-pgfplots-doesnt-work-miktex-2-9), but it still doesn't work.

I am using Miktex and Texstudio. I am also compiling via `dvips` since I am using `psfrag`. The compile command is:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape name
```

where `name` is just the file name without file extension, here `.tex`.

Comment: Why don't you use the standalone class for this?

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get is incomplete. If you invoke pdflatex from the command line, you will get a full error message:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "chapter-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{chapter}\input{chapter}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'chapter-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).
```

Your problem is different, but you may be able to resolve it in a similar way. For me, manually running 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "chapter-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{chapter}\input{chapter}"' got me the file that I needed, but this is not satisfactory for a large number of pictures. Further debugging using "\tracingall" resulted in this error:

```
\pgf@tempa ->pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "chapter-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{chapter}\input{chapter}" runsystem(pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "chapter-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{chapter}\input{chapter}")...disabled (restricted).
```

This can be resolved by running pdflatex with the "--shell-escape" option. The precise procedure to add this option depends on your tex editor. For TeXstudio, go to Options, Configure texstudio, Commands, and change "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex" to "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex". This fully fixed the problem.