# Attempting to export tikz to eps

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps, tikz-external

So, after having read the below thread:

[Attempt to export EPS figures from TikZ fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14030/attempt-to-export-eps-figures-from-tikz-fails)

I am able to generate .dvi versions of my figures. However, I need .eps, and it seems that the question above only covers getting the externalize library to work. It does so now, with no errormessages. But there is no eps-output.

Reading the manual, it seems I have to add "pdftops -eps {pdf file} {eps file}" to the "system call option". Below is seen my attempt at doing so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% set up externalization
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && 
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi pdftops -eps "\image".pdf "\image".eps}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % MikTeX uses a -enable-write18 instead of --shell-escape.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as you can see, having no idea what to put in place of {some file}, I just copied the form of what was already there. 
The above does not generate any errors, nor any .eps-files.

I am outputting to .ps format.

I hope someone can explain to me how to add the proper option =)

Comment: As a small note: LaTeXiT (on a mac) allows you to save your work in many formats, including eps. Its main purpose is to be able to include nice equations into other types of documents (Pages,Word,LibreOffice,etc.) but I use it to draw diagrams.

Comment: I have the same problem than Kaare. Did you find a solution? I run with Miktex...

Answer (score 6):

You were missing an `&&` before the `pdftoeps`, your quotation marks were in the wrong place (you had `"\image".ps` instead of `"image.ps"`), and `pdftoeps` is the wrong command to use to convert a postscript file to an encapsulated postscript file.  On my system, I have a command called `ps2epsi` which works.  I also tried it with `ps2eps` which also works (don't know the difference!).  Admittedly, I'm testing this on Linux so can't be absolutely sure that this will work for you with MikTeX, but give this a go and see if it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25524/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

% set up externalization
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && 
dvips "\image.dvi" && ps2epsi "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % MikTeX uses a -enable-write18 instead of --shell-escape.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(NB: Anyone testing this on Linux should comment out the optional argument to `\tikzexternalize`.)

Comment: Actually, that's not quite right.  That `pdftops` shouldn't be there ...

Comment: Okay, gotten rid of the `pdftops` and replaced it with `ps2epsi` instead.

Comment: The location of the `"` doesn't matter. The shell will remove them anyway before the program sees them. They are just there to escape any special characters in the filename. I updated http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz to add the missing `ps2eps`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not make this work. That is to say, copy-pasting the above code has exactly the same effect as the old code.

Comment: @Kaare: What happens if you run the commands individually?

Comment: I don't think I know what you mean. From DOS? dvips tikzFigure-figure0.dvi seems to work fine, ps2epsi tikzFigure-figure0.ps output.epi makes a pretty long error. The syntax for ps2epsi is supplied by the command itself ("Usage: ps2epsi <infile.ps> <outfile.epi>"). As I have previously had huge difficulties getting TexLive to work on my machine (ProTex was the second choice), I am beginning to think I should just send the ps-file to linux and do it from there, as there seems to be plenty of tools available on that platform.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1

Create a batch file as follows:

```
rem batch.bat takes an input file name WITHOUT extension.

del %1.pdf
del %1.eps

pdflatex %1
pdftops -level3 -eps %1.pdf

del %1.aux
del %1.log
```

For simplicity, save it in the same directory in which your input file exists.

### Step 2

Create a test input file as follows.

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For simplicity, save it in the same directory in which `batch.bat` exists.

### Step 3

Open MS-DOS prompt by pressing `Win+R`, typing `cmd` and hitting ENTER. The MS-DOS prompt brings up and navigate to your input file directory. Afterwards, type

[image]

and hit ENTER. Done, you will get both PDF and EPS outputs.

[image]

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, don't forget to upvote and give a green check mark. Because I noticed you have not done it yet for your other question. :-)

Comment: You don't need to pass `-enable-write18` to `pdflatex` in `batch.bat` because `pdftops` is executed directly outside `pdflatex`.

Comment: I get the following (after a lot of text describing the workings of MikTex):
D:\projekt\Talks & such\DelA-defence>pdftops -level3 -eps tikzFigure1.pdf
'pdftops' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: So, I guess the new question is where to get pdftops =) googling pdftops windows does not yield anything useful.

Comment: @Kaare: I don't use MikTeX. In TeXLive, this tool exists.