# How to export the eps file from the .tex file using pdfLaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, eps

How to export the image in `.eps` from the tex code using `PdfLaTeX` in **TeXStudio.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}  
        A\arrow{d}\arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}&B\arrow[red]{d}{\xi}\\
         C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta} & D 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I have tried with the code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244831/convert-tikz-to-eps-using-pdflatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}    
        A\arrow {d}\arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}&B\arrow[red]{d}{\xi}\\
         C \arrow[red]{r}[ blue ]{\eta} & D 
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I got the following error `File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture.` Also adding the following code in the preamble didn't help me.

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
        -halt-on-error
        -interaction=batchmode 
        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"
        && pdftops -eps "\image.pdf"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
```

I have found another help using `pdftops` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91275/how-to-save-a-figure-produced-by-tikz-save-export-as-eps-file), which is helpful for the `TeXWorks` users. Can any one please help me to export the `.eps` file of the image using `PdfLaTeX`?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25524/attempting-to-export-tikz-to-eps

Comment: @Macro That I tried and got the error `File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture.` But I didn't try the **steps 1,2,3**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`standalone` class can be used to create cropped figures but also to convert from `pdf` them to other formats like `png, jpg, ...` usually with `imagemagick` help. See, as example, [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible#11880)

OP wants to obtain an `eps` file using `pdflatex` from TeXstudio.

The idea is using `standalone` class to do all for us.

As I'm using MikTeX which has a `pdftops` converter (I don't know if its available on other systems), command

```
pdftops -eps file.pdf
```

can be used to convert a pdf file to encapsulated postscript. This command can be included as a `standalone` class option with:

```
\documentclass[convert={outext=.eps, command=\unexpanded{pdftops -eps \infile}}]{standalone}
```

`\unexpanded` is not mentioned in documentation but it's explained in [Martin's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51766/1952)

Therefore compiling with `pdflatex` a file like

```
\documentclass[convert={outext=.eps, command=\unexpanded{pdftops -eps \infile}}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}  
        A\arrow{d}\arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}&B\arrow[red]{d}{\xi}\\
         C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta} & D 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

will generate a pdf and eps results.

Important: `-shell-escape` must be added in configure options for pdflatex in TeXstudio

Comment: It would be better to compile with LaTeX instead: `latex -> dvips`

Comment: @pluton Do you mean `latex filename.tex` and then `pdftops -eps filename.pdf`? If so, what is the difference?

Comment: @Ignasi I tried with your code using `PdfLaTeX` and got only `.pdf` file. Where to add `-shell-escape` in the configure options for pdflatex in TeXstudio? In my case the `PdfLaTeX` has configuration `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.

Comment: @LitunJohn insert it between `pdflatex.exe` and  `%.tex`

Comment: @Marco The OP requests the use pdflatex (we do not really know why) but no, I was suggesting `latex filename.tex` and `dvips filename.dvi`

Comment: @pluton In my system, I am unable to get any `.dvi` output after running `LaTeX` due to the error `Some PostScript specials could not be rendered.` I don't know how to get rid of the error. So `PdfLaTeX` is my favorite.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you. Configuring the `PdfLaTeX` command line to `pdflatex.exe -shell-escape %.tex` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `\tikzexternalize` if the document is *stable* and you 
will make few modifications to `tikzpicture`,  it is better to handle it in 
separate files and include them as an image (or with `\input{test-tkz-1.tex}`). 
The `ltximg` script you can do the following:

```
$ ltximg  --eps --subenv --imgdir=mypics --extrenv=tikzcd  --margin=10 --prefix=tkz -o test-out test.tex
```

Now you will have a new document `test-out.tex` with the `tikzpicture` environments
converted into images (preserving the consistency of the fonts) and you will also have each 
`tikzpicture` environment in separate files (in case you need some extra 
modification) and one file `test-all.tex` with (only) all `tikzpicture`.

First check the documentation to see the options and conditions 
that the input file must meet.