# How do I export a TikZ-Feynman file as .eps?

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps, export, tikz-feynman

I would like to draw a Feynman diagram with Ti*k*Z. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi;
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\tikzfeynmanset{
every blob/.style={draw=green!40!black, pattern color=green!40!black},
every crossed dot/.style={blue},
}
\feynmandiagram [vertical=anu to nu] {
  nu [particle=\(\overline{\nu}\)] -- [anti fermion] b [blob],
  anu  [particle=\(\nu\)] -- [fermion] b,
  b   -- [fermion,bend right=10,edge label'=\(\nu\)] f1 [crossed dot],
  b   -- [anti fermion,bend left=10,edge label=\(\overline{\nu}\)] f1,
  b   -- [fermion,bend right=10,edge label'=\(\nu\)] f2 [crossed dot],
  b   -- [anti fermion,bend left=10,edge label=\(\overline{\nu}\)] f2,
  nu  -- [draw=none] anu,
  f1  -- [draw=none] f2,
};
\end{document}
```

How can I export the file not as `.pdf` but as `.eps`?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288691/how-to-export-the-eps-file-from-the-tex-file-using-pdflatex?noredirect=1#comment698451_288691

Comment: Run with LaTeX-> PS ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pdftops`, part of [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html),

```
$ pdftops -eps inputfile.pdf outputfile.eps
```

Comment: I don't get it installed, I don't know why. I downloaded the .exe file on my Mac and double-clicked, but the installation does not start.

Comment: It's a command-line program, you have to run it from a terminal