# Exporting TikZ to EPS using MacTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps, tikz-external

I have followed the instructions for exporting to an `.eps` file from a TikZ drawing provided here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8646/8078. However, I cannot get any of the methods to produce an `.eps` file successfully.

I am working on a MAC, OS 10.6.8, running MacTeX via TexShop.

When I use the following code, a `.pdf` is created, but no `.eps` file is created. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error 
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" &&
pdftops -eps "\image".pdf}}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/force remake}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3.5,xscale=4.5]

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[below, text width=2cm] {Before Tax Income $z$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[below left, text width=1.8cm] {After Tax Income $z - T(z)$};

\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1,2);
\draw (0,0) -- (1.5,1.5);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip (1,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0,0) -- (1.5,1.5);
\end{scope}

\draw[rotate around={45:(1,1)},red] (.6,1.1) node[left] {$L$} parabola bend (1,1) (1.4,1.1);

\draw[shift={(.125,.125)},rotate around={45:(1,1)},cyan] (.6,1.1) node[left] {$M$} parabola bend (1,1) (1.4,1.1);

\draw[shift={(.25,.25)},rotate around={45:(1,1)},ForestGreen] (.6,1.1) parabola bend (1,1) (1.4,1.1) node[right] {$H$};

\draw[dashed] (1,0) node[below] {\textcolor{red}{$z^{*}$}} -- (1,2);

\draw[dashed] (1.25,0) node[below] {\textcolor{ForestGreen}{$z^{*}+\triangle z^{*}$}} -- (1.25,2);

\path (.15,.1) node[right] {slope = $1-t$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8646/8078, I also try alternative ways to create the `.eps`, namely, using the following code, where the system call is changed, and `latex` is used to compile, rather than `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi;
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/force remake}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3.5,xscale=4.5]

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[below, text width=2cm] {Before Tax Income $z$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[below left, text width=1.8cm] {After Tax Income $z - T(z)$};

\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1,2);
\draw (0,0) -- (1.5,1.5);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip (1,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0,0) -- (1.5,1.5);
\end{scope}

\draw[rotate around={45:(1,1)},red] (.6,1.1) node[left] {$L$} parabola bend (1,1) (1.4,1.1);

\draw[shift={(.125,.125)},rotate around={45:(1,1)},cyan] (.6,1.1) node[left] {$M$} parabola bend (1,1) (1.4,1.1);

\draw[shift={(.25,.25)},rotate around={45:(1,1)},ForestGreen] (.6,1.1) parabola bend (1,1) (1.4,1.1) node[right] {$H$};

\draw[dashed] (1,0) node[below] {\textcolor{red}{$z^{*}$}} -- (1,2);

\draw[dashed] (1.25,0) node[below] {\textcolor{ForestGreen}{$z^{*}+\triangle z^{*}$}} -- (1.25,2);

\path (.15,.1) node[right] {slope = $1-t$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this case, I get the following error message:

> ./tikz_eps2.tex:55: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'latex
>   -shell-es cape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz_eps2-figure0" "\def\t
>   ikzexternalrealjob{tikz_eps2}\input{tikz_eps2}"; dvips -o
>   "tikz_eps2-figure0".p s "tikz_eps2-figure0".dvi; ps2eps
>   "tikz_eps2-figure0.ps"' did NOT result in a u sable output file
>   'tikz_eps2-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).  Please
>   verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is
>   'pdflat ex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or
>   something like that . Or maybe the command simply failed? Error
>   messages can be found in 'tikz_eps2
>   -figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

I hit return, latex continues to compile a `.pdf`. As a result, a `.ps` is created that I can open, but the `.eps` file that is created is "empty." That is, when I try to open the `.eps` it with `Preview`, I get the error "Warning: Empty Job. No PDF file produced." Or, if I open the `.eps` file in Adobe Illustrator, all that shows is a blank canvace.

Finally, I also use this syntax for the extranlize command:

```
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && 
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi &&
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
```

After this, I get the same result as in the second case.

I should also mention that I try to directly use `ps2eps` to convert the `.ps` an `.eps` in OS X Terminal. I get the following message in Terminal:

> Input files: /Users/nomad/Dropbox/tex_remote/TiKz/tikz_eps2-figure0.ps
>   Processing: /Users/nomad/Dropbox/tex_remote/TiKz/tikz_eps2-figure0.ps
>   Rendering with existing %%BoundingBox: 0 0 345 225 Calculating
>   Bounding Box...ready. %%BoundingBox: 4 3 332 225 Creating output file
>   /Users/nomad/Dropbox/tex_remote/TiKz/tikz_eps2-figure0.eps ... ready.

However, the resulting `.eps` is still "blank" as in the previous cases.

Comment: Are you sure you have `--shell-escape` enabled in your `pdflatex` command in TeXShop?  Your first example works fine for me, with the same setup.  In the TeXShop preferences, under the Engines tab, the command for `pdflatex` should be `pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape`. This was a recent change in TeXShop preferences. `--shell-escape` used to be enabled by default, but now it's not.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I can confirm that `--shell-escape` is enabled in my TeXShop preferences. I must also make a correction to my question. When I run the first example, no `.eps` is output, only a `.pdf` file. Can you confirm that running this on your system produces a well-functioning `.eps` version of the graphic?

Comment: If I compile your second code with `latex --shell-escape` I get the expected result (Mac OS X, 10.5, though; it shouldn't make any difference).

Comment: @stanford202 Yes, from `foo.tex` I get 3 output files: a `foo.pdf` file and two image files: `foo-figure0.pdf` and `foo-figure0.eps`.  The `.eps` file opens fine with Preview (which converts it to pdf) or for that matter, Adobe Illustrator (albeit with font substitutions).

Comment: Ok, I suppose there might be something wrong with my setup.

Comment: I think this actually is quite likely to happen with TeXShop >= 3.10.  I'm having similar, though not identical, problems.  The question would be how to do this without the command line.