# How to save a figure produced by tikz save/export as EPS file

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps

I use MiKTeX 2.9 and `tikz` package and use TeXworks to make simple figures, these are saved in pdf file by pdfLaTeX. I wish to have them as EPS file. I read here:
[Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz)
I use a simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% set up externalization
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && 
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi &&
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % MikTeX uses a -enable-write18 instead of --shell-escape.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and get the following error:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'latex -halt-on-error -interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "untitled-1-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{untitled-
1}\input{untitled-1}" && dvips -o "untitled-1-figure0".ps "untitled-1-figure0".
dvi && ps2eps "untitled-1-figure0.ps"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'latex -halt-on-error -interaction
=batchmode -jobname "untitled-1-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{untitled-1}    input{untitled-1}" && dvips -o "untitled-1-figure0".ps "untitled-1-figure0".dvi
 && ps2eps "untitled-1-figure0.ps"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'unt
itled-1-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that yo
u have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. So
metimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the comman
d simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'untitled-1-figure0.log'. If yo
u continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I see many have got the same error. I do not know what to do. Can somebody please help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You can do something like `pdftops --eps filename.pdf` for each PDF generated by the `TikZ` external library, but I recommend you to use the PDF images.

Comment: @user24203 if i may ask what is your objective of generating .eps figure ? IMHO these days .pdf is requested

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes, it seems easier to manually type the useful commands in a command window instead of going through the endless configuration steps of your LaTeX-ready text editor. Consider the following `myfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfrealjobname{myfile}
\begin{document}
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{myfile-f1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill(0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\endpgfgraphicnamed
\end{document}
```

Open such a command window in the working folder where your file `myfile.tex` is located and compile as follows:

```
latex --jobname=myfile-f1 myfile.tex
```

then

```
dvips myfile-f1.dvi
```

and you will obtain the desired properly cropped `myfile-f1.eps` file.

Comment: I followed your answer but obtained `myfile-f1.ps`. Not sure if relevant, but I'm on a MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: same for me. It is not `.eps` but `.ps`. It does not seem to be a big problem. You just rename the file with an .eps extension.

Comment: Why does it generate a two-page dvi to me? The first page is blank with a page number only and the second page has the picture and a page number.

Comment: I have a similar file with a tikz image, and after I run the first command above I get a .dvi file, which has the required image. But the .ps file output of the second command is empty when I open it. Would you know what is happening?

Comment: @Arun: without more information from you, no.

Comment: The resulting file is not cropped... Can latex or dvips crop the image straight away?

Comment: @remus This was an old solution. What do you get with the following code: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\fill(0,0) rectangle (4,4);\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}` and the same compilation commands?

Comment: @pluton It looks ok when using standalone. But I'm trying to embed the chain commands in tikzexternalize which uses the main file documentclass with a4paper.

Comment: @pluton I made a question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255462/cropping-an-image-genereated-with-latex-dvips-and-tikzexternalize

Comment: How to do this for multiple figures in a latex file?

Comment: @AHK Do you want to get multiple files with one figure per file?

Comment: @pluton yes, one file for one figure

Comment: @AHK can you translate your tex file into multiple tex files with only one figure each? Then you can compile all tex files in batch mode, to get the figures...

Answer (score 4):

Here are two routes for MiKTeX users. The first is similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8646/14497), but with additional notes.

### using *pdflatex* + *pdftops* with TeXworks

1. Download `pdftops` from [foolabs.com](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) (a PDF to PS/EPS converter). You'll find the 32-bit and 64-bit binaries for Windows in [xpdfbin-win-3.03.zip](ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdfbin-win-3.03.zip). To install it, extract `pdftops.exe` from this file and copy it to the installation directory `C:\Program Files\Xpdf\bin`. Remember to add `C:\Program Files\Xpdf\bin` to the system variable `Path` (*Start Menu* -> right-click on *Computer* -> *Properties* -> *Advanced System Settings* -> *Environment Variables* under the *Advanced* tab -> look for the system variable `Path` and edit its value).
2. In TeXworks, go to *Preferences* -> *Typesetting* tab, and add `--shell escape` to the list of arguments passed to the `pdflatex` compiler as shown below. [image]

Now run `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external} % set up externalization

\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % activate externalisation

\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && 
pdftops -eps "\image.pdf"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in TeXworks and you will obtain graphics in the EPS format.

### using *latex* + *ps2eps* with TeXnicCenter

1. Download [ps2eps.zip](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/ps2eps.zip) and follow the instructions to install `ps2eps`. You'll find some additional notes [here](http://n8miller.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/using-ps2eps-on-windows-to.html) on its installation under Windows.
2. You'll also need [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) and a
   Perl interpreter (one option is the free ActivePerl "Community
   Edition", available from
   [activestate.com/activeperl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl)).

   (The `ps2eps` script assumes you have the 32-bit Windows install of Ghostscript. If you install the 64-bit version the file `ps2eps.pl` must be changed as described at the end of this answer.)
3. In [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/), add `-enable-write18` to the list of arguments passed to the `latex` compiler (go to *Build*, then click on *Define Output Profiles*), as illustrated below. [image]

Now you can run `latex` on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external} % set up externalization

\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % activate externalisation

\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && 
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi &&
ps2eps -l "\image.ps"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in TeXnicCenter and you will obtain graphics in the EPS format.

If you installed the 64-bit version of Ghostscript, you'll need to open `ps2eps.pl` with a text editor and replace the two occurrences of `gswin32c` with `gswin64c`.

Comment: OP uses TeXworks as mentioned in Question. TeXnicCenter also is a good choice

Comment: [Texworks can be configured](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latex_->_dvips_->_ps2pdf) for `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`

Comment: This is perfect NUNO. I managed to get *.PS format. How can I make it to save as .EPS?

Comment: @user24203 to send a comment to NUNO use  `@NunoNunes` like i did. at command line `ps2eps FileName.ps` gives FileName.eps file. For more [ps2eps](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/ps2eps/doc/html/ps2eps.html)

Comment: @user24203 I left that bit out, sorry. it's now included in my answer.

Comment: @NunoNunes read `WHY ?` *Section* of [pro­grams like ps2epsi (a script dis­tributed with ghostscript) don’t al­ways cal­cu­late the cor­rect bound­ing box](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/ps2eps/doc/html/ps2eps.html)

Comment: @texenthusiast i was not aware of that, thank you! (+1)

Comment: @user24203 any success?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative response, the `ltximg` *script* automates this process, the
separate image files are include them as an image (or with `\input{test-tkz-1.tex}`). 
The `ltximg` script you can do the following:

```
$ ltximg  --eps --subenv --imgdir=mypics  --prefix=tkz -o test-out test.tex
```

Now you will have a new document `test-out.tex` with the `tikzpicture` environments
converted into images (preserving the consistency of the fonts) and you will also have each 
`tikzpicture` environment in separate files (in case you need some extra 
modification) and one file `test-all.tex` with (only) all `tikzpicture`.

First check the documentation to see the options and conditions 
that the input file must meet.