# pgfplots figures in publications

Tags: pgfplots

Journals usually ask for the figures in a publication to be in some specific formats (e.g. eps, svg, tiff etc). Now that I have used pgfplots to make all the figures in my article, what is the best course of action to convert all of the figures to e.g. eps? Should I use some kind of an external tool to extract all the figures (gpdfx, inkscape etc) from the current article and the convert them to the correct format, and then use `\includegraphics` to include them again? A lot of tedious work, surely there is a better option?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8641 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91275 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140796 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91472 (please let me know, if one of these works for you)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I believe none of them are very useful as I need to export all of the figures in one document into separate standalone files (pdf, eps or svg).

Comment: Don't use .eps for the final format but pgfplots and TikZ have a full-blown `externalize` library specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: I think that your question is exact duplicate of those questions introduced you by @LaRiFaRi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, thanks to percusse's comment, I researched the pgfplots' `externalize` library and found that adding these two lines

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

to my preamble did just what I wanted for no effort at all!

(Ryan's answer is also great, and thanks to him, but this is a better way.)

Answer (score 6):

One possible workflow would be to drop each `pgfplots` figure or `tikzpicture`: into a `standalone` document, which would give you a `.pdf` file of just that figure, which you could then convert using something else.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
    Ma       Mb      a
    200      50      5.6
    170      80      3.3
    140      110     1.0
    100      150     -1.6
    70       180     -3.9
}\caseone

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            title=Variable Net Force,
            xlabel={Acceleration},
            ylabel={Net Force},
            legend entries={Raw Data,Line of Best Fit},
            legend style={at={(0.973,0.03)},anchor=south east},
            width=\textwidth,]
                \addplot
                    [only marks, black] 
                    table[x=Ma, y=a]{\caseone};
                \addplot 
                    [smooth, black, very thin]
                    table[x=Ma, y={create col/linear regression={y=a}}]
                    {\caseone};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above would output just the plot in `pdf` format, which then can be converted to anything and including it with `\includegraphics` would work fine because the whitespace is trimmed.

If you're on a unix-like system you could then use ImageMagick Convert to convert all the images at once, for example if you named all your figures `figure1.pdf` `figure2.pdf` `figure3.pdf` then you could use `convert -density 600 figure*.pdf figure*.eps` to batch-convert them all, preserving numbering.