# Convert TikZ to EPS using pdfLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, miktex, texstudio, eps

I would like to convert my TikZ images to EPS format and save in a separate file while pdfLaTeX compiles my document, ideally. Note I am using MikTeX and TeXstudio.

Otherwise, I would like to be able to convert TikZ pictures into EPS from a LaTeX file using pdfLaTeX.

I've tried the method found [here](http://michaelgoerz.net/notes/creating-eps-files-from-tikz.html) but the pictures do not work entirely correctly. There is some cutoff (missing parts of the image), plus it is a pain to convert each figure this way.

Example code below.

*test.text*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes}

\pgfrealjobname{test}


\begin{document}
    \beginpgfgraphicnamed{levels}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\normalsize, every node/.append style={transform shape}]
        \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=1.5em, line width=0.05em] (n1) at (0,0) {1};
        \node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=1.5em, line width=0.05em] (n2) at (2,0) {2};     
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \endpgfgraphicnamed
\end{document}
```

In the command prompt:

```
latex --jobname=levels test.tex
dvips -o levels.eps levels.dvi
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want `eps` instead of `pdf`? `pdflatex --jobname=levels test.tex` will create `pdf` results not `dvi`.

Comment: Some journal papers require figures in eps format rather than pdf format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on @Ignasi answer and the link he posted about using an editor with PdfLaTeX, the solution is as follows:

From **[foolabs.com](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)** download xpdf and unpack to a location on your computer.

In **Computer Properties** Go to *Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables* and add the path of your particular *xpdfbin\bin* to the path. This will enable Windows to find the folder and use the executable *pdftops* on the command line.

In **TeXstudio**
Go to *Options -> Commands* and change the PdfLaTeX line to this:

```
pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

This will tell TeXstudio to use the above on the command line when you hit the compile button for a file.

Finally, in your **LaTeX Document**, add the following to the preamble:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
                                        -halt-on-error
                                        -interaction=batchmode 
                                        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"
                                        && pdftops -eps "\image.pdf"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
```

Then you can compile to your heart's desire as PdfLaTeX will generate pdf and eps versions of all your Tikz drawings!

Other info for a pertinent LaTeX build and how to do it for your particular case may be found in either of these two links suggested by @Ignasi:

1. [how-to-save-a-figure-produced-by-tikz-save-export-as-eps-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91275/how-to-save-a-figure-produced-by-tikz-save-export-as-eps-file/91277#91277)
2. [export-eps-figures-from-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz/8646#8646)

Also, this technique should work using the other tools for Pdf conversion in the xpdf package such as *pdftopng*.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `externalize` TikZ library does. 
Try to compile next code with command `pdflatex --shell-escape levels` (being `levels` the name of the file). As a result you'll get a `pdf` file with the whole document, but also another file called `levels-figure0.pdf` which contains the `TikZ` figure:

[image]

In fact you'll get as many `levels-figureXXX.pdf` files as `tikzpictures` you have in your `.tex` source. Next time you compile again your source file, all `tikzpictures` are not processed and replaced by corresponding `.pdf` results.

If any tikzpicture has been changed in the mean time, it's processed again, but only those which has been updated.

This default behavior can be changed introducing commands and options from `externalize` library whose information can be found in section "50 externalization library" (pp 597-610) from [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}%
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\normalsize, every node/.append style={transform shape}]
\node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=1.5em, line width=0.05em] (n1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5em, minimum height=1.5em, line width=0.05em] (n2) at (2,0) {2};     
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: So the library can recognize if the figure code was changed before to compile it? If not, simply use the pdf figure created before; if yes, compile it again and create the pdf again?

Comment: @Sigur: After better reading I think it remakes all of them by default. I'll confirm it later and correct my answer.

Comment: @Sigur: I've confirmed it. By default only edited figures are recompiled. Although you can change this behavior.

Comment: thanks for the attention. Indeed it is a very good tool.

Comment: Can this be used to make eps figures too?

Comment: @TheGuy Yes, you can use `pdflatex` which generates pdf files and convert them with `pdftops -eps pdffile epsfile`. Or use `latex` which produces `.ps` files for every figure.

Comment: @Ignasi I had to set `\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]` and call `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex` for this to generate the figures. However, I cannot compile using TeXstudio, I have to manually do this. Is there a way to make this all work in TeXstudio. I cannot seem to figure it out from the manual.

Comment: @TheGuy I've never used TeXstudio, but for sure that somewhere you can configure which commands it executes for compiling.Did you look in TeX.SX?

Comment: Tried it. No luck for me. Ugh.

Anyway, I attempted to use pdftops and I get an error saying it is not a recognized command. Is this something I need to download separately?

Comment: Apparently for windows, one needs to download pdftops.exe from (http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) to get the functionality for making a pdf into an eps.

Comment: @TheGuy I think these ones provide better answers than mine:    http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91275/how-to-save-a-figure-produced-by-tikz-save-export-as-eps-file/91277#91277 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz/8646#8646

Comment: @Ignasi Ahah! Figured it out based on the first link you sent and the help you gave! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `\usetikzlibrary{external}` if the document is *stable* and you 
will make few modifications to `tikzpicture`,  it is better to handle it in 
separate files and include them as an image (or with `\input{test-tkz.tex}`). 
The `ltximg` script you can do the following:

```
$ ltximg  --eps --subenv --imgdir=mypics --prefix=tkz -o test-out test.tex
```

Now you will have a new document `test-out.tex` with the `tikzpicture` environments
converted into images (preserving the consistency of the fonts) and you will also have each 
`tikzpicture` environment in separate files (in case you need some extra 
modification) and one file `test-all.tex` with (only) all `tikzpicture`.

First check the documentation to see the options and conditions 
that the input file must meet.