# Chemfig schemes and tikz external

Tags: chemfig, tikz-external, chemnum

Is there any way to externalise a `chemfig`scheme with `tikz`?

At the moment a good fix to externalise simple chemfig pictures is to place them inside a `\begin{tikzpicture}`...`\end{tikzpicture}`environment. This can be done automatically, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245106/41319).

I am aware that arrows drawn with `\chemmove` won't work, as per [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303411/41319) answer, but I am hoping to find a way to externalise simple schemes, like the one below.

This is my (updated) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize    
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\schemestart
\chemfig{A}\arrow{->[\scriptsize above]}\chemfig{B}
\schemestop
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, disabling `tikzexternal`before `schememestart`and re-enabling it immediately afterwards generates the corresponding external figure only for 'A'. Adding a second `\tikzexternalenable`generates a picture also for B. See below:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzexternaldisable
\schemestart
\tikzexternalenable
\chemfig{A}\arrow{->[\scriptsize above]}\tikzexternalenable\chemfig{B}
\schemestop
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

**Edit:** it turned out my MWE was too minimal to reproduce the issue. Here's a list of simple things I found originate errors. I suspect they can be easily fixed.

1. My arrows are redefined so as to automatically print out label in
   `scriptsize` (now triggered manually in the updated MWE).

   This, however, gives the following error:

   > TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig
   >   \nullfont

   That is true any time the font size or weight is varied, anywhere in
   between `\schemestart` and `\schemestop` when in a `\tikzpicture`
   environment. For example, `\chemnum`'s standard `\cmpd{name}` gives
   a similar error because the compound's label is printed as
   `\textbf{label}`. Wrapping the incriminated text in brackets doesn't fix it.
2. `\parbox` and `\mbox`don't work, possibly because they'd be nested environments?
3. **Bonus**: It would be a lifesaver if all my schemes could be redefined a posteriori to be wrapped in `tikzpicture`, as it was done for `\chemfig`in the answer linked above.

Comment: I do not understand the question... If I wrap the `\schemestart ..  \schemestop` with `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`, the figure is externalized correctly. What are you looking for?

Comment: You're right! See my updated question.