# How to install pdftops?

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps

I use MikTeX + TeXstudio and use to TikzEdt to draw graphics.

I want to export figures from TikzEdt to TeX.

As I know, firstly I shall install `pdftops` to transform figures in order to `.eps` format. So, I am trying to install `pdftops` and to follow the steps specified [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91275/how-to-save-a-figure-produced-by-tikz-save-export-as-eps-file).

I downloaded it and extracted  `pdftops.exe` from folder 64-bit in `xpdfbin-win-3.03.zip`. Now, I run it. But `C:\Program Files\Xpdf\bin` isn' t created. Must I create it manually?

And I added `C:\Program Files\Xpdf\bin` to the system variable Path (Start Menu -> right-click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables under the Advanced tab -> look for the system variable Path and edit its value) I can' t do next steps.

Or do you know more simply method to export figures from tikzEdt to .eps format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why did you download `pdftops`? It is part of MiKTeX (`miktex-poppler-bin-x64-2.9`).

Comment: :)Sorry, since I am new , I haven't enough informations about these topics. I just want to export figures from TikzEdt to TeX by transforming figures to ".Eps" format and when I search the topic in tex.stackexchange, I come accross some links, I shared one of them it above. So, I try to the steps in the link.

Comment: why do you not simply use pdftex and include the pdf directly?

Comment: So, I hear that some journals want to figure as .Eps format in Tex. Hence I want to learn it.

Comment: Some do, but I still haven't seen any journal that turned down an article written with pdflatex using pdf files. Other journals just have not updated their requirements in years.

Comment: It seems very strange workflow, first you use an editor that generates tikz (tex syntax) that you could input directly into tex then somehow you make a pdf of that then need to convert the pdf to eps so you can include an eps into latex so that it can be converted later to pdf. (but if pdftops is part of miktex using that should be easy enough if that's what you want to do) (i don't use miktex so can't help with the details)