# How to extract/convert tikz to a format suitable for powerpoint

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I am trying to extract/convert a `tikzpicture` to a format that is suitable for powerpoint without losing quality. The code that I have found and adjusted is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}

\pgfrealjobname{mytikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{outputpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [height=7cm, width=10cm, title=\textbf{Title}, xlabel= XYZ, ylabel = ABC]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-30) (30,-30) (60, 0) (90, 30) (120, 60) (150, 90) (200, 140)} node[pos=0.115,pin=-360:{A}] {};
\addplot coordinates {(0, -40) (30, -40) (30, 60) (60, 60) (90, 60)(120, 60) (150, 60) (200, 60)} node[pos=0.734,pin=-90:{B}] {};
\legend {{XYZ}, {ABC}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\endpgfgraphicnamed
\end{document}
```

`mytikzpicutre` is the name of the file with the initial graph. I named the output as `outputpicture`; the entire code is saved under the name output. However I get an error:

```
pgf: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image wdpgfgraphicnamed'.
```

Could anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you considered making a separate `.tex` file using the `standalone` class, with the content just being the picture? That's my approach: LaTeX -> PDF -> IrfanView -> Paste into PowerPoint.

Comment: @JosephWright I tried it your way but I dont really know how IrfanView works, hope to receive alternative solutions, thanks in anyway!

Comment: IrfanView is just a front end here, but one I find convenient. What you need to have is a copy of GhostScript installed: IrfanView uses it to do the PDF conversion. I usually set the resolution for conversion to 600 x 600 dpi: there is a setting in IrfanView for that. There are other approaches, but the basic idea is that PowerPoint can't properly work with vector images, which includes PDFs, so you need a raster (bitmap). We've got other general questions on this sort of conversion.

Comment: Alternatively, you can export the TikZ picture to `.eps` format, as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8646/18228, and insert the `.eps` image in powerpoint.

Comment: @KevinC I have tried it out but still without success

Comment: You can try the Python script tikz2pdf to create a single pdf picture with your drawing: http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/tikz/process/

Comment: @Robert Is there any possibility to post the correct code including my tikzpicture data, so that I can use it? I am not that strong with Latex and I dont really know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinC Could you please show me the right code including my tikzpicture data? I receive an error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Python script "tikz2pdf" (http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/scripts/tikz2pdf): Save the tikz image in a separate file (e.g. foo.tex):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [height=7cm, width=10cm, title=\textbf{Title}, xlabel= XYZ, ylabel = ABC]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-30) (30,-30) (60, 0) (90, 30) (120, 60) (150, 90) (200, 140)} node[pos=0.115,pin=-360:{A}] {};
\addplot coordinates {(0, -40) (30, -40) (30, 60) (60, 60) (90, 60)(120, 60) (150, 60) (200, 60)} node[pos=0.734,pin=-90:{B}] {};
\legend {{XYZ}, {ABC}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Run "tikz2pdf foo.tex".

Note that if you haven't run the script before it will generate a template file called .tikz2pdf.tex and this does not include the "pgfplots" package default.

If you don't want to use the tikz2pdf script you can copy the template file it provides:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [height=7cm, width=10cm, title=\textbf{Title}, xlabel= XYZ, ylabel = ABC]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-30) (30,-30) (60, 0) (90, 30) (120, 60) (150, 90) (200, 140)} node[pos=0.115,pin=-360:{A}] {};
\addplot coordinates {(0, -40) (30, -40) (30, 60) (60, 60) (90, 60)(120, 60) (150, 60) (200, 60)} node[pos=0.734,pin=-90:{B}] {};
\legend {{XYZ}, {ABC}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compile this using pdflatex and you get a pdf file that is tightly cropped around your image.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I have tried it out and it basically generates the standalone class file. I do lose the quality since I then use the snapshot tool to integrate the graph into the powerpoint file. I guess an eps file would really solve my problem, at least I hope so! nevertheless, thank you for your effort! I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can also compile with the classical latex and dvips (e.g. using "dvips -q foo.dvi -E -o foo.eps"). I'm on a Mac that won't open eps files, so I'm sure if this works.

Comment: I am getting following error message: `! LaTeX Error: Environment axis undefined.`