# Tikz externalization: Latex dvi/ps produces a4paper boundary-box around figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am successfully using tikz in combination with externalization and pdflatex for some time now.
But now I need to switch to latex->dvi->ps. 
I followed the instructions from the tikz documentation and read a lot of user posts.

I can compile the minimal example (see below) without any errors,
but the external image (ps) generated by dvi2ps has the size of an a4-paper.
Therefore latex places the figure after "Text before image" and "Text after image".

Is it possible that the bounding box is not determined correctly?

I've tried a similar scenario a couple of months ago on a Mac OS X system and it worked.
Now, I am running a Windows system with the most recent MikTeX version (I updated all packages).

Does anybody know, if it is a bug in dvips or in tikz? Or maybe I did something wrong.
Thank you for your help!

PS: I also tried a lot of other system calls (pdflatex -> pdftops) and everything from here:  [Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz)
without any success.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" &&
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi }}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

Text before image.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Text after image.

\end{document}
```

Edit: 
I tried the minimal example on another windows system and got the same a4paper box.
Calling

```
dvips -E* -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi
```

instead of the code above leads to a figure without any bounding box. Therefore latex inserts the image on top of the text.
It is also possible to change the format as an argument of dvips, but I do not intended, to specifiy a fixed bounding box as a general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (was) a bug in PGF CVS. Apparently, it entered with PGF 3.0.0 and worked with older PGF releases.

I fixed it a couple of weeks ago; it will be gone with the next version of the `external` lib.

Your options are

- wait for the next stable PGF release (long)
- wait for the next stable pgfplots release 1.11 and use `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` (within the next weeks)
- install the PGF unstable from http://pgf.sourceforge.net/
- modify the system call such that it uses `pstoeps` as last item (might be unavailable in windows)