# Missing Display Fonts at eps Figure Export from Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, eps, tikz-external, shell-escape

This question is similar to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz/8646#8646?newreg=6456e32449d542e2819eb8f696f41ffe). The accepted answer there seems to be working in general, I get a readable `.eps`-file. If I open it however it looks pixelated and the fonts seem weird.
At compilation I receive a notification saying

```
Config Error: No display font for 'Symbol'
Config Error: No display font for 'ZapfDingbats'
```

The pdf created seems just fine to me, for use in other documents I would need an `.eps`-file though. I can of course manually convert the pdf-files, but as there are many I would like to automate the process if possible.

I am running Windows 8 with MikTeX portable and use `pdflatex`.

**EDIT:**

I decided to include a `MWE` here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} 


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
                                    -halt-on-error
                                    -interaction=batchmode 
                                    -jobname "\image" "\texsource"
                                    && pdftops -eps "\image.pdf"}}

\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{pic1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}

       \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};

   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The execution command is

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape  %.tex
```

That does run through and creates a `.pdf` file that is just fine (document file as well as the figure itself) and an `.eps` file, which is pixelated as described above.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't understand why you need an .eps figure?

Comment: Thank you. I would like to use .eps figures to include the graphics in other programs such as MS PowerPoint.

Comment: Power Point doesn't accept .pdf graphics?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Microsoft (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-PDF-file-content-into-a-PowerPoint-presentation-5e7719d5-508c-4c07-a3d4-68123c373a62) suggests using a screenshot, which of course renders the use of vector file formats useless.

Comment: What about .svg?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. .emf might work. I technically don't need it to be an .eps-file. I just started with that because that's what my search in this forum revealed

Comment: I mentioned `.svg` because `dvisvgm` is now included in MiKTeX . I don't know if .pdf can be converted to .emf. Is it a purely vector format? Maybe [this link](http://download.cnet.com/Free-PDF-to-EMF-Converter/3000-18497_4-76168847.html) might be of interest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent Siep Kroonenberg's `epspdf-setup` to convert from pdf to eps. I don't know if it can do batch conversion, but as it has a `texlua` script as a backend I suppose it must be possible to write a small script for that. It uses `pdftops.exe` that comes with MiKTeX.

Here is a screenshot of the resulting .eps file for you M.W.E. (that I converted to the `standalone` class). As you can see, the fonts are not pixellated:

[image]n

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Did you convert the .pdf-file manually after creation or is this the .eps-file created "on the fly"?

Comment: I converted it manually, with `tightboundingbox` option.