# How to externalise tikz figures using the latex compiler instead of pdflatex compiler?

Tags: tikz-external

I am working with eps figures, and I would like to externalise some figures thought external tikz library. Thus, I prefer to use latex compiler rather than to use pdflatex compiler. But it is not working.

I am using Windows 8.1 OS, with Miktex 2.9.700 and Texstudio 2.12.14.

I made a MWE based on [Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz) TeX topic and Tikz and PGF manual for version 3.0.0, page 617:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% set up externalization

\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname \image \texsource && dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi && ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18] % MikTeX uses a -enable-write18 instead of --shell-escape.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it is returning an error as follows:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'latex -halt-on-error -interaction
```

Is there any configuration that I must change in texstudio or I am mistaking in any procedure?

Comment: I thought eps is (equivalent to) a superset of pdf. What makes you not consider compiling pdfs as usual and convert them to eps?

Comment: Every figure of my work is in eps format. There are a lot of figures (50 approximately), and to convert everyone to pdf format would be a painful task. Besides that, I should change the compilation method whenever I converted a tikz picture to pdf format. But my work comes being compiled with eps figures from the beginning. Thus, I could to convert every tikz picture to pdf format, but after I should convert each one to eps format, what would be another painful task.

Comment: IDK... if you have magickimage, a command line tool, you can do `convert *.pdf *.eps` to convert everything at once; plus 50 is not a large number.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `\tikzexternalize` if the document is *stable* and you 
will make few modifications to `tikzpicture`,  it is better to handle it in 
separate files and include them as an image (or with `\input{test-in-tkz.tex}`). 
The `ltximg` script you can do the following:

```
$ ltximg --latex --eps --subenv --imgdir=mypics --prefix=tkz -o test-out test-in.tex
```

Now you will have a document with the `tikzpicture` environments converted into 
images (preserving the consistency of the fonts) and you will also have each 
`tikzpicture` environment in separate files (in case you need some extra 
modification). First check the documentation to see the options and conditions 
that the input file must meet.