# tikz to eps quality loss

Tags: tikz-pgf, eps

I generated an image with `tikz` which consists in an external image and a series of labels.
I tried to convert it in `.eps` format by following the procedure presented here [Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz). As result the `.pdf` image is good while I have a huge quality degradation in the `.eps` file.

In the preamble I included the following lines

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error 
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
pdftops -eps "\image".pdf;
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize
```

and then I run the command

> latex --shell-escape

Here a complete example of the code

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikzscale} 


\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error 
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
pdftops -eps "\image".pdf;
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize




\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node {\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{circle}};
  \node {$\mathcal{SSSSSSSS}_1$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Original:

[image]

And here the `.pdf` and `.eps` images

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be beneficial to know which latex installation you use. And we would like more details as to what `huge quality degradation` actually means. All in all, it wopuld be better if you provided a full example that others can copy and which gives the quality problem on your system, then others can try it on their own separate systems

Comment: You have not given many clues but I would assume that for some reason pdftops is rasterising the page so your eps is a fixed resolution bitmap.  Try instead pdf2ps  I don't think that ever rasterises the image (or pdftops has options to control rasterisation see pdftops --help)

Comment: I edited the question providing a running example and the results. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And where is `circle`? I'd say the circle image is irrelevant, the image should just be the SSS part

Comment: You also haven't told us which latex installation you are using.

Comment: The eps I get out on my system using TeXLive 2021 and Ubuntu 18.04 is clearly vector graphics (I removed the image that I don't have)

Comment: I don't know, but to me it looks like the exact same result. The only difference is, that one of them has an aliasing filter. Are both images viewed in the same vector graphics viewer? It might be only caused by the viewer program. If I recall correctly, post script doesn't support transparencies and maybe also not aliasing.

Comment: And what do you consider to be the better quality? I prefer the later as the aliasing should be done by the viewer program as the last step. Otherwise the result will be not pleasant.

Comment: @daleif I have Tex Live 2019/Debina and I work on a Ubuntu 20 machine

Comment: @MaestroGlanz The views are the same. Moreover the font of the label is not the same between pdf and eps image. Thank you again.

Comment: @Fly It is the same font. Just one time with aliasing, the other time without it.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the aliasing?

Comment: @Fly It depends, where the anti-aliasing comes from. The question is: Which software does the anti-aliasing.