# TexStudio stopped compiling pdflatex after using CLI for the first time

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, texstudio, mac, mactex

At the moment I am writing my PhD thesis using TexStudio editor. Up until this morning, TexStudio compiled the document with PdfLateX without a problem, as always. Apart from that, in the past I created some Tikz figures without any issue either. However, since I have to draw more complex Tikz figures, today I decided to create them in a separate file. This way, I would export them  as .eps figures, and append them in the main PhD file as a graphic content.

To export these figures in .eps format, I tried to implement the answer from this post: [Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz), which required to run a CLI command:

```
latex --shell-escape
```

To my surprise, after that, TexStudio stopped working properly for the first time. In fact, it could not compile new tex files from zero, only those which had been compiled in the past (those that have already the extra files like .aux, .log ...). I have run many tests like setting default options, renaming paths for the pdflatex command, nothing works. I tried to restart the Macbook, uninstall Mactex, uninstall Texstudio, uninstall TexLive, then reinstalling everything again (with brew). Nothing. I always get the same error:

```
Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex
```

It is true that I can always rely on CLI with "pdflatex" command to compile the document. In addition, I proved that TexShop editor from Mactex also works. However, I would like to use TexStudio as I have been doing so far for the last couple of years. I feel that I am missing something (maybe trivial) to solve this bug. Maybe it is the CLI command that changed paths to libraries or something. I am a little bit desperate now, so any help is very welcome.

Thanks,